# div with an image behind wrapper not working

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website which is white, so I dont have any background assigned. But I want to add some blue gradient details on two parts of the website. #bg_top would be placed on the top to the left and #bg_bottom should be placed on the bottom to the right. Of course this is not working exactly the way I want...

This is how its displayed on my html:

```
<body>

<div id="bg_top"></div>

<div id="wrapper">
</div>

<div id="bg_bottom">
</div>

<footer>
</footer>
```

The #bg_top works perfectly. It does display itself behind the wrapper but the bg_bottom is giving me the problem as its well placed, but its visually between the wrapper and the footer. Therefore I used z-index but its also not working. Also the strange thing is that the bottom and left parametres dont make any difference. This is the CSS code:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 925px;
    height: 1355px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#bg_top{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('../_img/2_body/bg/bg_top.jpg');
    z-index: -1;
}

#bg_bottom{

    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    background-image: url('../_img/2_body/bg/bg_under.jpg');
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Could somebody help me? I've tried everything...

thank you

Comment: I presume you have a `</body>` in the real page?

Comment: Yes of course... but I dont want to put all the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already got to my answer... I needed the pictures to be behind the wrapper. The bottom picture sticked to the top right part of the footer and the top picture at the same level than the header. Thanks to the input I saw it was very simple...

```
 <body>

<header>

<div id="bg_top"></div>

</header>


<div id="wrapper"></div>


<footer>
<div id="bg_bottom"></div>
</footer>

</body>
```

So after I applied absolute position and a z-index and picture as backgound done... behind the wrapper and in its place. This was the final CSS code:

```
#bg_top{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url('../_img/2_body/bg/bg_top.jpg');
    z-index: -1;
}



#bg_bottom{

    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('../_img/2_body/bg/bg_under.jpg');
    bottom: 155px;
```

Any other doubts maybe I can help...
        right: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are not wrapping the bg_top and bg_bottom inside the wrapper. It works perfectly when you do it.Please find the fiddle I used

http://jsfiddle.net/meetravi/sL5jm/

Good Luck !

Comment: Let me know if the above fiddle makes sense to you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you very much, the fiddle makes total sense to me. In the wrapper it works perfectly. So thanks for that... But... I need the two divs to be behind my wrapper, but visible. So thats why I did the div out from the wrapper. Is it possible to have that effect?

Answer (score 0):

With position: relative, if you want it visually inside the wrapper, you need to put the HTML inside the wrapper.

Comment: Yes, I understnad that. But I want the divs to be out of my wrapper. But visible of course... How can I do that? place out of the wrapper both divs and give them different z-index but... it doesnt work fir me